# How to access domain models of microservices in web api controller

Tags: json, azure, swagger, microservices, azure-service-fabric

I have a. Net core microservice project.
The architecture goes like below
1. Application Project
2. Service Project (WebApi project) 
3. Microservices project 
4. Interface layer

Since data, code and config should be inside the microservices, i have added all the domain models inside microservice project. But i access these microservices using a controller in WebApi project through the interface using service proxy class.

So my question is if my microservice is going to return Employee object, how should i add it as return type in my controller. Since controller has dependencies only to interface project and not the microservice project, i can't access the domain model. I end up creating another domain model in webapi project or use dynamic variable type as return type.

Also swagger doesnt return model object format since i used dynamic variable.

Is there any better way to do it.?

Comment: Use data transfer objects that map from your domain model and are returned by your web api project.

Comment: Thanks.. I will try that

Answer (score 1):

Can we safely assume that both the web api project and the microservices project are Stateless Services?

Can't you create DTO's in the interface project and have the microservices project return them?

But I do wonder, if the api is just a gateway to a stateless service, why bother with the stateless service at all? I would put that logic in the api. I mean, what is the benefit otherwise?

Or put an http endpoint on the microservices service and remove the remoting communication listener. That way your frontend can directly talk to the service and you can remove the api controllers (the microservice effectively becomes your api).